# How to check and change function volatility in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, functions, ddl

I have a function that I think is defined as `volatile`, but I now know I want it `stable`.

How can I check the function volatility (`volatile`, `stable`, `immutable`) of a certain function?

When a function is defined as `volatile`, can I change the volatility to `stable` by using a `create or replace function` query? Or does the function needs to be dropped and created again but this time as `stable`?

```
create or replace function my_function()
returns int as $$
    select a
    from my_table
    order by 1
    limit 1
$$ language sql stable;
```

I checked the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/xfunc-volatility.html) for this, but it doesn't mention changing volatility.

Answer (score 3):

I checked the documentation [again](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterfunction.html), and the answer to my second question is, yes you can alter it using the `alter function` query.

```
alter function my_function() stable;
```

Also, I see that checking for function volatility has been asked and answered before.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54452415/how-to-check-whether-a-function-is-immutable